# Copy named columns from matrix to another

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix

```
  x <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=5,ncol=6)
dimnames(x) = list( c("row1", "row2", "row3","row4","row5"), c("0", "1","2","3","4","5"))

   0  1  2  3  4  5
row1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
row2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
row3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
row4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
row5 NA NA NA NA NA NA

    y = matrix( c(2, 4, 3, 1,7,6, 5, 7,1,9), nrow=5, ncol=2) 

    dimnames(y) = list( c("row1", "row2", "row3","row4","row5"), c("0", "3"))
```

I have the names of the two columns of y, for example: column="0" and column="3". They are not consecutive.

And I'm trying to replace columns 0 and 3 in x by the columns "0" and "3" getting this matrix as result:

```
      0  1  2  3  4  5
row1  2 NA NA  6 NA NA
row2  4 NA NA  5 NA NA
row3  3 NA NA  7 NA NA
row4  1 NA NA  1 NA NA
row5  7 NA NA  9 NA NA
```

I'm trying with this

```
x[,as.numeric(colnames(y))] <- y
```

But get index error

Comment: There are no dimnames on either of those matrices.  Maybe you want  `x[,c(3,5)] <- y`?

Comment: Thanks, this works fine but if I have 60 columns instead of 2 to replace?

Comment: Does `y` have named columns?  Please clarify in your post because in your example `y` has no column names

Comment: y is the result of the table command (2-way table), I got the names of the columns using the names function,

Comment: But that's not what you show in the question.  Please update to show a more representative example for `y`

Comment: Another way to see the problem is that I have an y dimnamed matrix where each column name is a number but those numbers are not consecutive and I have to complete missing columns with NA columns. In this example I tried to create first the NA matrix and "fill" it with the columns I have.

Comment: Maybe then you want `x[,as.numeric(colnames(y))] <- y`

Comment: Thanks, it works, the problem now is when dimnames(y) = list( c("row1", "row2", "row3","row4","row5"), c("0", "5")) because in x I don't have a "0" column. I think I should create x starting from column 0 but when I have about 100 columns I can't create it manually